# Python passing arguments to function Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, arguments

I am writing a Flask application script and have encountered a function that accepts arguments and functions outside of the flask app in a standalone script but will not accept the the 'TFEVT_node_id'argument I pass to it inside of the Flask app. Here is the Flask code:

```py
#################################################
# Flask Setup
#################################################
#app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
#################################################
#global variables
TFEVT_node_id = ''
token = ''
#################################################
# CityIQ API calls
#################################################
def get_token():
    print("Get Token")
    url = 'https://auth.aa.cityiq.io/oauth/token'
    querystring = {"grant_type":"client_credentials"}

    response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client,secret), params=querystring).json()
    token = response['access_token']
    print("Token Received")
    return token

#given a specific subasset this function returns the CityIQ traffic events for a given period of time in minutes
def get_traffic(TFEVT_node_id, lookback_minutes):
    url_string = '/events'
    url = "https://sandiego.cityiq.io/api/v2/event/assets/"+TFEVT_node_id+url_string
    ts = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    CityIQ_Current_TS = int(ts*1000)
    CityIQ_TS_Calc_TS =  datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=lookback_minutes)
    CityIQ_Starttime_TS =  int((ts-(lookback_minutes*60))*1000)
    querystring = {"eventType":"TFEVT","startTime":CityIQ_Starttime_TS,"endTime":CityIQ_Current_TS,"pageSize":"100"}
    payload = ""
    headers = {
            'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token),
            'Predix-Zone-Id': "SD-IE-TRAFFIC",
            'cache-control': "no-cache",
            }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
    return(response)

#give it an CityIQ node ID and it will return the asset TFEVT child .
def get_asset_TFEVT(node_id):
    url = "https://sandiego.cityiq.io/api/v2/metadata/assets/"+node_id+"/subAssets"
    payload = ""
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token),
        'Predix-Zone-Id': "SD-IE-ENVIRONMENTAL",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers).json()
    for i in response['assets']:
        if any('TFEVT' in i for i in [i][0]['eventTypes']):
            global TFEVT_node_id
            TFEVT_node_id = ([i][0]['assetUid'])
    return(TFEVT_node_id)

#test def that should be removed in production
def test(TFEVT_node_id, lookback_minutes):
    found_cars = get_traffic(TFEVT_node_id, lookback_minutes)
    print(found_cars)
    return(found_cars)

#################################################
# Flask Routes
#################################################
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    global token
    token = get_token()
    return 'documentation comming soon!'

@app.route('/test/<string:node_id>')
def go(node_id):
    global token
    token = get_token()
    global TFEVT_node_id
    TFEVT_node_id = get_asset_TFEVT(node_id)
    cars_list = []
    lookback_minutes = 15
    env_output = {}
    ccars = test(TFEVT_node_id, lookback_minutes)
    cars_list.append(ccars)
    env_output.update({'Cars' : cars_list})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Again, I am getting the desired result when these functions are run outside of a Flask app. Inside of the Flask app (running the code above) returns a TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response.  I have traced that back to the 404 response in the gettraffic function where the lookback minutes variable is getting through but the TFEVT_node_id isn't.

I am new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your `go()` function does not have a return. A response is expected. See: [About responses](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#about-responses).

Comment: thanks for the response however that wasn't the problem... Even with a return on the go() function it is still providing the same error.